# Issue connecting new wordpress install to pre-existing database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've recently run into a situation helping another individual who overwrote their site folder when installing a new copy of Wordpress. The original wordpress database is still intact and when attempting to update the connection string in the wp-config.php file it does connect to the old database but just brings me to the setup page (/wp-admin/install.php). It doesnt appear to be recognizing any of the database tables that already exist. Is there a solution to get around this?

Comment: I'd suggest installing on a new database. Add your activated theme to the theme folder and import the wp_posts from the old database to the new one. You can also copy the other tables.

Comment: If all of the tables are in tact, and you connect a WordPress installation to that database, it will not prompt you to install WordPress.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the `$table_prefix` in your `wp-config.php` file matches the actual prefix of your database tables.